# 初回起動時にファイルをバンドルからコピーするメソッドがコンパイルエラー

Tags: ios, swift

iOSアプリケーション起動時にバンドルからファイルをコピーしたいのですが、コンパイルエラーになります。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class dic: Object {
    dynamic var ID = 0
    dynamic var yomi = ""
    dynamic var kigou = ""
    dynamic var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}


class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

private var lexicon: UILexicon!
var myCollectionView : UICollectionView!

var button11: UIButton!
var button12: UIButton!
var fFastBoot = true
var fPri = CGFloat(20)
var ifontSize = 18.0
var RPath = ""
var sTextNum: Int = 0
var sTexst: String = "12345"
var cellNum: Int = 0
var tText:String = ""
var sText:String = ""
var listYomi: [String] = [];
var listKigou: [String] = [];
var listDate: [NSDate] = [];
var layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()


// Portrait表示におけるキーボードの高さ
private var portraitHeight: CGFloat = 190.0
private var portraitWidth: CGFloat!

// Landscape表示におけるキーボードの高さ
private var landscapeHeight: CGFloat = 100.0
private var landscapeWidth: CGFloat!


override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

func createPath() -> String {

    let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory , NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let databaseStr = "/Dictionary.realm"
    let dbPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingString(databaseStr)

    // BEGING MODIFICATION
    let fileMan = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath)) {    // The database does not already exist in Documents directory
        if let source = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingString(databaseStr) {
            if !(fileMan.fileExistsAtPath(source)) {
                print("RealmDB - file \(databaseStr) not found in bundle")
            } else {
                var error:NSError?

                if !(fileMan.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: dbPath)) {
                    print("RealmDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
                    print("Error - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // END MODIFICATION

    return dbPath
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createPath()
    print(createPath())

    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .System)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), forState: .Normal)
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

    let nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.view.addConstraints([nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint])

    // CollectionViewのレイアウトを生成.
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    // サイズの設定
    layout.itemSize.height = 10
    layout.itemSize.width = 10
    // Cell一つ一つの大きさ.
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(25, 25)
    // Cellのマージン.
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
    // セクション毎のヘッダーサイズ.
    layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0,0)
    // 横スクロール
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal  //.Vertical

    // CollectionViewを生成.
    myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.frame.size.height = 30
    myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 100
    myCollectionView.frame.offset(dx: 2, dy: 2)
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)

    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    print(myCollectionView.delegate)
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    print(myCollectionView.dataSource)

    // Cellに使われるクラスを登録.
    myCollectionView.registerClass(CustomUICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

    myCollectionView.sizeToFit()
    print(myCollectionView.frame)

    let inputText = "）"

    let realm = try! Realm(path: createPath())
    let results = realm.objects(dic).filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText).sorted("date", ascending: false)
    cellNum = 0
    print(realm)
    print(results)
    for result in results {
        print(result.kigou)
        listYomi = listYomi + [result.yomi]
        listKanji = listKigou + [result.kigou]
        listDate = listDate + [result.date]
        cellNum = cellNum + 1
    }
    print("test2")

    if cellNum == 0{
    }else{
        cellNum = cellNum - 1
    }
    print("test3")

    InsertText("（")
    view.addSubview(myCollectionView)

    myCollectionView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 500)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var myNativeBoundSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let myNativeBoundSizeStrW: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.width
    let myNativeBoundSizeStrH: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.height

    var myWidth = myNativeBoundSize.width
    var myHeight = myNativeBoundSize.height
    // 向きの判定.

    if isLandscape() { // Landscapeだったら、
        let orientation = "Landscape"
        // Landscape用の viewを表示する。
        //print(orientation)

    } else { // Portraitだったら、
        let orientation = "Portrait"
        // Portrait用の viewを表示する。
        //print(orientation)
    }
    var sKishu = "iPad"
    if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(320.0, 330.0)" {
        // iPhone, iPod touch
        sKishu = "iPhone"
        myWidth = 30
    }else if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(768.0, 500.0)" {
        myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 764
    }else if String(self.view.bounds.size) == "(1024.0, 500.0)" {
        myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 1020
    }
    print(String(self.view.bounds.size))
    //print(sKishu)

    if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(1024.0){
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(20)
        //print("iPad縦")
    }else if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(768.0){
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(11)
        //print("iPad横")
    }else{
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(10)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(10)
        //print("Non")
    }

    if fFastBoot == false {
        self.button11.frame = CGRectMake(0,3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2) ,myHeight - CGFloat(6))
        self.button12.frame = CGRectMake(myWidth, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2), myHeight - CGFloat(6))
    }else{

        self.button11 = UIButton(type: .System)
        self.button11 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2) ,myHeight - CGFloat(6)))
        self.button11.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
       self.button11.addTarget(self, action: "btnUp11:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        self.button11.addTarget(self, action: "btnDown11:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)

        self.button12 = UIButton(type: .System)
        self.button12 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(myWidth, 3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2), myHeight - CGFloat(6)))
        self.button12.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.button12.addTarget(self, action: "btnUp12:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        self.button12.addTarget(self, action: "btnDown12:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)

    }

    self.button11.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(String(myNativeBoundSizeStrH), comment: "("), forState: .Normal)
    self.button12.setTitle(NSLocalizedString(String(myNativeBoundSizeStrW), comment: ")"), forState: .Normal)
    if fFastBoot == true {

        self.button11.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(ifontSize))
        self.button12.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat(ifontSize))

        self.view.addSubview(self.button11)
        self.view.addSubview(self.button12)
        fFastBoot = false
    }
}

func btnDown11(sender: UIButton){
    //fDub = false
    self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
func btnUp11(sender: AnyObject){
    self.button11.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let tText = "あ"
    InsertText(tText)
}

func InsertText (str: String){
    tText = ""
    sTextNum = sTextNum + 1
    sText = sText + str
    let proxy = textDocumentProxy
    proxy.insertText(str)
    serchText(str)
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

private func isWidth() -> CGFloat {
    // 現時点で Landscape表示が適当かどうかを判断する。
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let screenW = self.view.bounds.size.width
    return screenW
}

private func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    // 現時点で Landscape表示が適当かどうかを判断する。
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let screenH = screenSize.height
    let screenW = screenSize.width
    let isLandscapeNow =  !(self.view.frame.size.width ==
        screenW * ((screenW < screenH) ? 1 : 0) +
        screenH * ((screenW > screenH) ? 1 : 0))
    return isLandscapeNow
}

override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
        textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
}

// セルの幅自動修正
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var size: CGSize = listKanji[indexPath.row].sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20.0)])
    print(CGSizeMake(size.width + 20.0, 25))
    return CGSizeMake(size.width + 20.0, 25) //self.flowLayout.itemSize.height)
}

/*
Cellが選択された際に呼び出される
*/
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
    print(listKigou[indexPath.row])
}

/*
Cellの総数を返す
*/
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(cellNum)
    return cellNum
}

/*
Cellに値を設定する
*/
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : CustomUICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomUICollectionViewCell
    //cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row.description
    print(indexPath.row)
    cell.textLabel?.text = listKigou[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func serchText(inputText: NSString){
    let realm = try! Realm(path: createPath())
    let results = realm.objects(dic).filter("yomi BEGINSWITH %@", inputText).sorted("date", ascending: false)
    cellNum = 0
    for result in results {
        print(result.kigou)
        listYomi = listYomi + [result.yomi]
        listKigou = listKanji + [result.kigou]
        listDate = listDate + [result.date]
        cellNum = cellNum + 1
    }
    if cellNum == 0{
    }else{
        cellNum = cellNum - 1
    }
}
}

class CustomUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    var textLabel : UILabel?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // UILabelを生成.
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height))
        textLabel?.text = "nil"
        textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        // Cellに追加.
        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel!)
    }
}
```

下記の箇所でコンパイルエラーが起こり、ビルドできません。

```
fileMan.copyItemAtPath
```

Comment: タイトルにiPad、Realmという言葉がありますが、特有の問題ではないと思います（ので編集しました。ご了承ください）。開こうとしているファイルパスはどこでしょうか？単にアプリ（エクステンション）がアクセス可能な領域に関する理解が足りないだけという気がします。

Comment: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/62470796-5F59-4344-AA88-8EC57D2644D2/Dictionary.realm　ですが、いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ソースを上記に追加しました。自動取得しています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: パス取得というより、そこのパスにファイルをインストールする方法がわからないのが原因かもしれません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーの起こってるところを書かないとわからないですね。`try Realm(path)`を実行してるところとその前後のコードを載せてください。

Comment: コードを乗せました。しかし、このコードでは、データベースのコピーが失敗しています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 前提として、このコードで正しいのかも不明です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: あなたのコードが間違ってることは明らかですが、コードの断片を適当に補完して実行してもこちらでは再現しませんね。。。あなたがおかしいと考えている動作が何なのか再現しないことには対処は難しいので、コードの断片ではなく、全体か、プロジェクト全体を共有することなどはできませんか？

Comment: テストコード全体を乗せました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このコードはコンパイルできてるんですか？新しく追記された「エラー箇所」というのはコンパイルエラーではないですか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27328/discussion-between-kishikawa-katsumi-and-nicora)しましょう。

Comment: 書き換えました。fileMan.copyItemAtPathのみ置き換えコード不明でエラーですが、それ以外は通ると思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27329/discussion-between-kishikawa-katsumi-and-nicora)しましょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 2では`NSError`を使ったエラー処理は`do〜try〜catch`構文に変わっているので、旧来の書き方ではコンパイルエラーになります。

以前と同様の処理をするには、たとえば下記のように書きます。

```
do {
    try fileMan.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: dbPath)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("RealmDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
    print("Error - \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。実機で動くようになりました。
これで、Dictionary.realmが正しく実機にインストールされていると考えてよいのでしょうか？

また、「（」の入力（button1、1024.0と表示）を複数回押した時、当然候補幅が違うものが候補になり、候補表示の幅が正しく表示されない現象が起こります。
これはこれで、調べても解決できない場合、別事案として、質問させていただきます。